# Issue in migrating database after adding refinerycms gem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2, refinerycms

I am integrating refinerycms in existing application and followed steps mentioned in http://www.refinerycms.com/guides/with-an-existing-rails-app

My `gemfile` contains following:

```
gem 'refinerycms', github: 'refinery/refinerycms', branch: 'master'
gem 'refinerycms-i18n', github: 'refinery/refinerycms-i18n', branch: 'master'
```

Adding gem 'refinerycms', '~> 3.0.0' to gemfile also generates same error:

> Error==> Mysql2::Error: Table 'refinery_base_model_translations' already exists: CREATE TABLE refinery_base_model_translations (id int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, refinery_base_model_id int(11) NOT NULL, locale varchar(255) NOT NULL, created_at datetime NOT NULL, updated_at datetime NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB**

Comment: Perhaps your system has just got in a funny database state, as you were editing migrations... try running `rake db:drop; rake db:create; rake rb:migrate`

Comment: @TomLord I have already done that. but no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Shefalee Chaudhary Commenting out these lines in the migration will fix your issue:

```
 #::Refinery::PagePart.create_translation_table!({
 #  :body => :text
 #})

#::Refinery::Page.create_translation_table!({
  #  :title => :string,
  #  :custom_slug => :string,
  #  :menu_title => :string,
  #  :slug => :string
 # })
```